# Using array to check is an item included in string?

Tags: javascript

I was thinking about doing an array to make my current `string.includes() || string.includes()...` code shorter, as checking for many words can make that list long, but I couldn't find an easy way to replicate this with array.

`array.includes(string)` only seems to check is the string specifically that, so if there's something else in that string too it wont work, which is pretty much the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: There are other array methods? Like some, every, filter, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```js
const myString = "Hello";
const arrayOfStrings = ["H", "U", "W"];

const hasString = arrayOfStrings.some(el => myString.includes(el))

console.log(hasString)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't only want to make `string.includes() || string.includes()...` shorter, but you also want to output all strings that are a substring as a collection, you can use `map` and filter `falsey` outputs, like this:

```js
let array = ["ab", "a", "abc", "abd", "cd", "ce"];

let res = array.map(e=>"abcdef".includes(e)?e:null).filter(e=>e!=null)

console.log(res);
```

If you still want true/false output, you can use reduce, like this:

```js
let array = ["ab", "a", "abc", "abd", "cd", "ce"];

let res = array.map(e=>"abcdef".includes(e)).reduce((a,b)=>a||b,false)

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is more like that a string would be a full sentence, and if that sentence includes a word listed in an array, it would then run a piece of code with if.

Comment: Then the second snippet is what you will need :) Instead of "abcdef", use your sentence.